# T-SQL OPENXML no results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, openxml

I'm storing an XML in my database and want to extract the values of that XML. Doing that with OpenXML, but I get no results. What am I doing wrong in here?

This is the first part of the XML

```html
<WebService xmlns="...">
  <DeelnemersMetVrijeVelden>
    <OutputSchema>
      <Envelope xmlns="...">
        <Body>
          <zoekDeelnemersGewijzigdNaResponse>
            <deelnemer>
              <achternaam>Toor</achternaam>
```

And this is the T-SQL I've written:

```html
DECLARE @XML nvarchar(max), @hDoc INT  
SET @XML = (SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(nvarchar(max),REsultaat) FROM Eduarte_Deelnemers_XML ORDER BY DatumAangemaakt DESC)

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT  *
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'WebService/DeelnemersMetVrijeVelden/OutputSchema/Envelope/Body/zoekDeelnemersGewijzigdNaResponse/deelnemer', 1)
WITH
(
achternaam varchar(100) 
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

Comment: Your @xml should be xml string, not a query

Comment: @AlexKudryashev When I make XML an xml, it still get nothing unfortunately

Comment: `sp_xml_preparedocument` is the pre-SQL Server 2005 way of handling XML; using the [XML methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods) (`.value`) is much simpler. Look into `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`, because the parts you've now cut out with the `xlmns="..."` are what's causing the problem: you need to specify the namespaces to select the elements.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the full XML, as the bits you've snipped out seem to be the issue

Answer (score 1):

XML Namespaces matter.

In XML documents each element is assigned to a particular XML Namespace and when querying them you need to reference that namespace to identify the elements, e.g.:

```sql
declare @xml xml = N'
<WebService xmlns="http://tempuri.org/MyWebService">
  <DeelnemersMetVrijeVelden>
    <OutputSchema>
      <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <Body>
          <zoekDeelnemersGewijzigdNaResponse>
            <deelnemer>
              <achternaam>Toor</achternaam>
            </deelnemer>
          </zoekDeelnemersGewijzigdNaResponse>
        </Body>
      </Envelope>
    </OutputSchema>
  </DeelnemersMetVrijeVelden>
</WebService>';

with xmlnamespaces(
  N'http://tempuri.org/MyWebService' as svc,
  N'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as soap
)
select achternaam.value(N'text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)') as [text]
from @xml.nodes(N'/svc:WebService/svc:DeelnemersMetVrijeVelden/svc:OutputSchema/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/soap:zoekDeelnemersGewijzigdNaResponse/soap:deelnemer/soap:achternaam') x(achternaam);
```

Alternatively you use the wildcard namespace to match elements solely by their name, but this is **highly not recommended** - not only is it inefficient but could return incorrect data in cases where the same-named elements could be present from different namespaces:

```sql
select achternaam.value(N'text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)') as [text]
from @xml.nodes(N'/*:WebService/*:DeelnemersMetVrijeVelden/*:OutputSchema/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:zoekDeelnemersGewijzigdNaResponse/*:deelnemer/*:achternaam') x(achternaam);
```